# Estimators of the Fisher information, advantages, disadvantages?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, fisher-information

I am reading a paper, which defines two estimators of the Fisher information. The first is the well-known negative hessian of the log-likelihood at the ML estimate, the second is
$$ \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta} l_t(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_T, \boldsymbol y_t) \frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta} l_t(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_T, \boldsymbol y_t)', $$
where $T$ is the sample size, $\boldsymbol\theta$ is the parameter vector, $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_T$ is its ML estimate, $l_t$ is the log-PDF of observation $t$, and $\boldsymbol y_t$ is the $t$-th observation. Both estimators are consistent, but the author prefers the second one because it is always positive semi-definite. If so, why is the negative hessian so commonly used? Does it have any theoretical advantages over the second estimator?

Comment: One way to avoid non-invertibility condition of the Hessian matrix is to compute the Hessian matrix as an average over multiple observations, i.e., in this case $T$ observations.

Comment: @maxtron, thank you. Do you have any resources on the topic?

Comment: Another possible explanation is as follows: Fisher information matrix is the expectation of the outer product of the partial derivative of loglikelihood function with respect to $\boldsymbol\theta$. If a closed form expression of the expectation cannot be found, it is replaced by an averaging operator.